# Firebase function triggering on auth displayName update?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I want to use a Firebase function to update the `users` node when someone changes their `displayName` in Firebase auth.

In particular, when they first sign up, I don't know how to include their `displayName` to the call to `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword`. I can only provide the email and password... so I immediately then call `user.updateProfile({ displayName })` on the object inside the returned promise. That works, but then in my Firebase functions, the `functions.auth.user().onCreate` call doesn't include the `displayName`.

So, is there something like `functions.auth.user().onUpdate`? I couldn't find anything in the reference docs.

Comment: There is on onUpdate, but you could use a database trigger instead.

Comment: Sorry, typo.  There is NO onUpdate.